# jsoup to get a particular id from a html file

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a html file like

```
<div class="student">
<h4 id="Classnumber100" class="studentheading">
   <a id="studentlink22" href="/grade8/greg">22. Greg</a>
</h4>
<div class="studentcategories">
<div class="studentneighborhoods">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to use JSOUP to get the url =  /grade8/greg  and "22. Greg".

I tried with selector

```
    Elements listo = doc.select("h4 #studentlink22");
```

I am not able to get the values.

Actually I want to select based on Classnumber100
There are 300 records in the HTML page , with the only thing consistent is " Classnumber100.

So I want my selector to select all the hrefs and text after classnumber100.
How can I do that.

I tried 
            doc.select("class#studentheading"); and many other possibilities but they are not working

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I followed http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html and based on that I used #id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, multiple elements should not share the same id, so each of these elements should *not* have the id `Classnumber100`.  However, if this is the case, then you can still select them using the selector `[id=Classnumber100]`.

If you're only interested in the `a` tags inside, then you can use `[id=Classnumber100] > a`.

Upon re-reading the question, it appears that the `h4` tags you're interested in share the `class` attribute of `studentheading`.  In which case you can use the class selector, ie

```
doc.select(".studentheading > a")
```

Comment: sorry it is not ID, I mean same class name

Comment: Thanks bdares this resolved my issue. can you please tell me why you have > a. I understand .studentheading is the ID. but how > a works here

Comment: `>` indicates that you're about to give a child selector.

Answer (score 1):

The select method looks for the html tag, here h4 and a, and then secondarily the attributes if you tell it to do so. Have you gone to the jsoup site as the use of select is well described for this situation.

e.g.

```
// code not tested
Elements listo = doc.select("h4[id=Classnumber100]").select("a");

String text = listo.text(); // for  "22. Greg"
String path = listo.attr("href"); // for  "/grade8/greg"
```

.